# Import parent directory module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to import a module that sits in a parent directory. I get an error (see below) when I try to import the parent module. How can I import this module correctly in Python 3?

> ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package (line 1)

Directory Structure:

```
module1:
    __init__.py
    module1.py

    module2:
        __init__.py
        module2.py

        module3:
            __init__.py
            module3.py
```

module3.py code:

```
from ... import module1 # error here
from .. import module2

print("module 3")
```

Answer (score -1):

A good practice is to create a repository to your project, see the figure and the code bellow:

[image]

**The code:**

module1.py

```
def hello():
    return 'hello world!'
```

module2.py

```
from module1.module1 import hello

print (hello())
```

**Output:**

```
hello world!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Why the downvote? have you (who voted) a better solution?